# How to check if the file from wc is in /trunk or /branch - TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

Let's say that I work in /trunk, and I switch only specified files to /branch, and not the whole wc. This allows me to make general changes in /trunk and I can get updates from other colleagues, while I add some new features in /branch for testing purposes. After a while, I will not be sure which files are in /trunk, and which are in /branch.

I could switch back and forth between /trunk and /branch for making the changes in relevant repository, but this is a tedious work.

I know if I look at file [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzspF.png) that it shows where the file is, but is there an easy way to see the same thing in Windows Explorer?

P.S. In the end, is it an good idea to do so? It looks OK for me because later I don't have to merge all files that were not intended to be changed in the /branch.

Comment: What do you mean by *"if I look at file URL"* ?

Comment: @LaurentH. just edited my question. In file properties (windows properties) you can see the file URL.

Comment: A alternative solution could be to add the $URL$ keyword in your source files, and to add the `svn:keyword` property with `URL` value to your project. In this way the repository URL of each file will be present in your files, and you could know if it comes from trunk or from branch.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was stupid and didn't see that in 'Commit' or 'Check for modifications' window I can see the URL of all of my modified files.

What I found out while having a mixed repository with files in WC in different branches, a little bit misleading while making a commit of the whole WC is that it shows the files will be committed in let's say Branch1. If one file from WC is in Branch2 it won't be committed to Branch1, but in Branch2 where it actually belongs and in the end it's correct way to do it.